# Mysql php ¿Como puedo hacer un where que se cumpla sin afectar a dos valores diferentes?

Tags: php, mysql, where

Hola tengo una lista de categorias donde cada una pertenece a una receta distinta,
mi idea es que me aga un update en prefijo y me ponga un 1 siempre y cuando la categoria
no pertenezca ni a 4 ni a 6 traté de hacerlo pero no me deja, me actualiza todas.
Si pongo !=4 solamente me deja actualizar todas excepto la 4 que es lo que interesa pero quiero que se puedan actualizar todas excepto la nº4 y la nº6 muchas gracias compañeros! Osea poner  en prefijo "1"  excepto las categorias mencionadas.

```
<?php
 include ('conexion.php');
 $query = "UPDATE Recetas
 SET prefijo = '1' where categoria !=4 and !=6";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 if($query){
     header("location:index.php");
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que te puede servir el operador NOT IN

```
<?php
 include ('conexion.php');
 $query = "UPDATE Recetas
 SET prefijo = '1' where categoria not in(4,6)";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 if($query){
     header("location:index.php");
      }
?>
```

Otra opción sería:

`where categoria != 4 and categoria != 6`

Información al respecto: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6904/sql-not-in-operator/